# Foursquare sub-category search

Tags: java, android, foursquare

I can get a list of categories and all nested subs as well, but the only category I want to search is 'food'.  What I need back is a list of subcategories for food.

Searching categories is done with: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories?oauth_token=[auth_token]&v=20150501

Is there a known way to just search for subcategories if I provide a category id?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `categoryId=...` from your query.  You can find the IDs here: https://developer.foursquare.com/categorytree

At the time of writing the categoryId for food is `4d4b7105d754a06374d81259`

Comment: tried https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories?oauth_token=[AUTH_TOKEN]&v=20150503&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259  and it is still returning all categories and subcategories.  I just want subcategories for food

Answer (score 0):

There is a danger in what I am about to suggest, but here goes.

You could create a sample app which hits https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories?oauth_token=[oAuthToken]&v=20150506, parses the json response and stuffs the results into a database. With this database populated, copy it (and necessary model files) into your real app.

Using this local category database, your app can search for just parent categories (Arts & Entertainment, Food, etc.), or just subCategories within a given parent category (brazillian restaurants, cafes, etc.), and so on.

The danger is that if Foursquare chooses to change their category data, your local source will be out of date. You will need to have a way to update your data and, of course, ensure your app handles the change(s).